# How to get result of multiples queries in a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `dummy_names` table which contains random first_names and last_names. In the db, where there is a first_name for an entry, the last_name is NULL and vice versa.

I'm trying to write a scope that returns a random name (a random first_name + a random last_name from that able).

**What am I doing wrong here...?**

```
scope :random_name, lambda {
    fname = self.where('first_name IS NOT NULL').first
    lname = self.where('last_name IS NOT NULL').first
    fname.first_name.to_s + " " + lname.last_name.to_s
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here we go

```
#in your initializer
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def self.random
      if (c = count) != 0
        find(:first, :offset =>rand(c))
      end
    end
  end
end



#in your model
def self.random_name
  "#{self.where('first_name IS NOT NULL').random.first_name} #{self.where('last_name IS NOT NULL').random.last_name}"
end
```

Comment: btw: better would be a function random_first_name and random_last_name, just to be dry :P